# Clear-net browsing with Lynx over Tor

Tags: security, bash, networking

This project is designed to enable clear-net browsing over the Tor network with the Lynx web-browser. Currently everything *seems* to be functioning as intended, however, it would be most appreciated if anyone could point out mistakes and/or ways that this project can be improved.

---

### Questions

- Are there any mistakes in this project that would harm the privacy of those using this project?
- Any additional features needed?
- Is there a way to add `.onion` Top Level Domain look-up support to Lynx browser?

> Note, currently for `.onion` addresses result in the following error...

```
Looking up 127.0.0.1:9999
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1:9999
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
Alert!: HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed
Data transfer complete

lynx: Start file could not be found or is not text/html or text/plain
      Exiting...
```

> ... so while clear-net browsing is groovy, for some reason browsing hidden services be going a bit goofy.

---

### Requirements

Prior to utilizing this project, the Lynx web browser should be installed, and `bash --version` should report a version number of `4` or greater.

Optional dependencies include [`firejail`](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail) and `socat`, for process sandboxing and DNS over Tor respectively.

---

### Setup

The [*`ReadMe`*](https://github.com/paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx/tree/main/.github) file contains more detailed instructions for setup, but the TLDR is...

- Clone

```
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/paranoid-linux
cd ~/git/hub/paranoid-linux

git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx.git
```

- Link/Install

```
cd torrific-lynx

sudo ./update-configs.sh

ln -s "${PWD}/torrific-lynx" "${HOME}/bin/"
```

- Use

```
torrific-lynx 'https://duckduckgo.com'
```

- Exit when done by pressing the <kbd>q</kbd> key to quit

---

### Source Code

> Note, source code for this question is maintained on GitHub at [`paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx`](https://github.com/paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx/blob/main/torrific-lynx), what is included here are the scripts, configuration file, and shared functions required to test/review without need of any Git *fanciness*.

#### [`torrific-lynx.cfg`](https://github.com/paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx/blob/main/torrific-lynx.cfg)

```
include:/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg

cso_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
finger_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
ftp_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
gopher_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
https_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
http_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
newspost_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
newsreply_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
news_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
nntp_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
snewspost_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
snewsreply_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
snews_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
wais_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/
no_proxy:http://127.0.0.1:9999/


FORCE_SSL_COOKIES_SECURE:TRUE
PERSISTENT_COOKIES:FALSE
```

#### [`torrific-lynx`](https://github.com/paranoid-linux/torrific-lynx/blob/main/torrific-lynx)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


## Find true directory script resides in, true name, and true path
__SOURCE__="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [[ -h "${__SOURCE__}" ]]; do
    __SOURCE__="$(find "${__SOURCE__}" -type l -ls | sed -n 's@^.* -> \(.*\)@\1@p')"
done
__DIR__="$(cd -P "$(dirname "${__SOURCE__}")" && pwd)"
__NAME__="${__SOURCE__##*/}"
__PATH__="${__DIR__}/${__NAME__}"
__AUTHOR__='S0AndS0'
__DESCRIPTION__='Enables clear-net browsing over the Tor network via Lynx web browser'


_cfg_path="${__DIR__}/torrific-lynx.cfg"
_url='https://check.torproject.org/'
_useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'
# _useragent='L_y_n_x/2.8.9dev.16 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/3.5.17'
_verbose=''
_disable_firejail=''
_disable_socat=''
_firejail_lynx_profile="/usr/local/etc/firejail/lynx.profile"
_firejail_socat_profile=""
_cloud_flare_hidden_service='dns4torpnlfs2ifuz2s2yf3fc7rdmsbhm6rw75euj35pac6ap25zgqad.onion'


## Provides: 'falure' <line-number> <command> exit-code
source "${__DIR__}/shared_functions/modules/trap-failure/failure.sh"
trap 'failure "LINENO" "BASH_LINENO" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${?}"' ERR

## Provides:  'argument_parser <ref_to_allowed_args> <ref_to_user_supplied_args>'
source "${__DIR__}/shared_functions/modules/argument-parser/argument-parser.sh"


__license__(){
    _year="$(date +'%Y')"
    cat <<EOF
${__DESCRIPTION__}
Copyright (C) ${_year:-2020} ${__AUTHOR__:-S0AndS0}

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published
by the Free Software Foundation, version 3 of the License.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
EOF
}


usage() {
    local _message="${1}"
    cat <<EOF
${__DESCRIPTION__}


--help      -h

    Prints this message and exists


--license   -l

    Prints license and exits


--cfg-path  --cfg='${_cfg_path}'

    Lynx configuration file path


--useragent='${_useragent}'

    User agent string to submit to remote servers


--verbose   -v

    Prints full Lynx command and options prior to running


--disable-firejail

    Disables Firejail customizations, note system defaults are **not** modified


--disable-socat

    Disables usage of Socat for DNS over Tor


--firejail-lynx-profile --lynx-profile="${_firejail_lynx_profile}"

    Firejail profile to use for Lynx sandbox


${_url}

    Web address to load at start-up


## Example usage


    ${__NAME__} 'https://check.torproject.org/'
EOF

    if (("${#_message}")); then
        printf >&2 '\n## Error: %s\n' "${_message}"
    fi
}


#
#    Read & save recognized arguments to variables
#
_args=("${@}")
_valid_args=('--help|-h|help:bool'
             '--license|-l|license:bool'
             '--verbose|-v:bool'
             '--disable-firejail:bool'
             '--disable-socat:bool'
             '--useragent:print'
             '--cfg-path|--cfg:path'
             '--firejail-lynx-profile|--lynx-profile:path'
             '--url:print-nil')
argument_parser '_args' '_valid_args'
_exit_status="$?"


((_help)) || ((_exit_status)) && {
    usage
    exit ${_exit_status:-0}
}

((_license)) && {
    __license__
    exit ${_exit_status:-0}
}


[[ -e "$(which lynx)" ]] || {
    usage 'Cannot find executable path for lynx'
    exit 1
}

[[ -f "${_cfg_path}" ]] || {
    usage "Cannot find configuration file for path -> ${_cfg_path}"
    exit 1
}


_lynx_opts=(
    -cfg="${_cfg_path}"
    -useragent="${_useragent}"
)


_firejail_opts=(
    --private
)

! ((_disable_firejail)) && ! ((_disable_socat)) && {
    _firejail_opts+=(
        --hosts-file="${__DIR__}/hosts"
        --dns='127.0.0.1'
    )
}

! ((_disable_firejail)) && [[ -f "${_firejail_lynx_profile}" ]] && {
   _firejail_opts+=(
      "--profile=${_firejail_lynx_profile}"
   )
} || {
   usage "No firejail profile found at -> ${_firejail_lynx_profile}"
   exit 1
}


_socat_opts=(
    'TCP4-LISTEN:443'
    'reuseaddr'
    "fork SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:${_cloud_flare_hidden_service}:443"
    'socksport=9150'
)
_socat_opts=("$(printf '%s\n' "$(IFS=,; printf '%s' "${_socat_opts[*]}")")")


kill_socat() {
    local _socat_pid="${1:?No PID provided!}"
    ((_verbose)) && {
        printf 'Killing socat PID -> %i\n' "${_socat_pid}"
    }
    sudo kill "${_socat_pid}"
    local _ps_search="$(ps aux | grep "${_socat_pid}" | grep -v grep)"
    (("${#_ps_search}")) && {
        # printf >&2 'Trying to kill socat again PID -> %i\n' "${_socat_pid}"
        # sudo kill "${_socat_pid}"

        ## TODO: Find cleaner way of killing socat process

        printf >&2 'Trying to killall socat\n'
        sudo killall socat
    }
}


[[ -e "$(which firejail)" ]] && ! ((_disable_firejail)) && {
    _lynx_path="$(which -a lynx | head -2 | tail -1)"
    [[ -e "$(which socat)" ]] && ! ((_disable_socat)) && {
        ((_verbose)) && {
            printf '# DEBUG: sudo %s %s &\n' "$(which socat)" "${_socat_opts[*]}"
        }
        ## TODO: Find cleaner way of asking for elevated permissions
        sudo echo "Starting socat..."
        sudo "$(which socat)" ${_socat_opts[@]} &
        _socat_pid="$!"
        trap "kill_socat ${_socat_pid}" RETURN SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
    }

    ((_verbose)) && {
        printf '# DEBUG: %s %s -- %s %s %s\n' "$(which firejail)" "${_firejail_opts[*]}" "${_lynx_path}" "${_lynx_opts[*]}" "${_url}"
    }
    "$(which firejail)" "${_firejail_opts[@]}" -- "${_lynx_path}" "${_lynx_opts[@]}" "${_url}"
} || {
    ((_verbose)) && {
       printf '# DEBUG: %s %s %s\n' "$(which lynx)" "${_lynx_opts[@]}" "${_url}"
    }
    "$(which lynx)" "${_lynx_opts[@]}" "${_url}"
}
```

---

#### [`shared_functions/modules/argument-parser/argument-parser.sh`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/argument-parser/blob/master/argument-parser.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


# argument-parser.sh, source it in other Bash scripts for argument parsing
# Copyright (C) 2019  S0AndS0
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published
# by the Free Software Foundation; version 3 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


shopt -s extglob


_TRUE='1'
_DEFAULT_ACCEPTABLE_ARG_LIST=('--help|-h:bool' '--foo|-f:print' '--path:path-nil')


arg_scrubber_alpha_numeric(){ printf '%s' "${@//[^a-z0-9A-Z]/}"; }


arg_scrubber_regex(){ printf '%s' "$(sed 's@.@\\.@g' <<<"${@//[^[:print:]$'\t'$'\n']/}")"; }


arg_scrubber_list(){
    printf '%s' "$(sed 's@\.\.*@.@g; s@--*@-@g' <<<"${@//[^a-z0-9A-Z,+_./@:-]/}")"
}


arg_scrubber_path(){
    printf '%s' "$(sed 's@\.\.*@.@g; s@--*@-@g' <<<"${@//[^a-z0-9A-Z ~+_./@:-]/}")"
}


arg_scrubber_posix(){
    _value="${@//[^a-z0-9A-Z_.-]/}"
    _value="$(sed 's@^[-_.]@@g; s@[-_.]$@@g; s@\.\.*@.@g; s@--*@-@g' <<<"${_value}")"
    printf '%s' "${_value::32}"
}


return_scrubbed_arg(){
    _raw_value="${1}"
    _opt_type="${2:?## Error - no option type provided to return_scrubbed_arg}"
    case "${_opt_type}" in
        'bool'*)  _value="${_TRUE}"      ;;
        'raw'*)   _value="${_raw_value}" ;;
        'path'*)  _value="$(arg_scrubber_path "${_raw_value}")"  ;;
        'posix'*) _value="$(arg_scrubber_posix "${_raw_value}")" ;;
        'print'*) _value="${_raw_value//[^[:print:]]/}"          ;;
        'regex'*) _value="$(arg_scrubber_regex "${_raw_value}")" ;;
        'list'*)  _value="$(arg_scrubber_list "${_raw_value}")"  ;;
        'alpha_numeric'*) _value="$(arg_scrubber_alpha_numeric "${_raw_value}")" ;;
    esac

    if [[ "${_opt_type}" =~ ^'bool'* ]] || [[ "${_raw_value}" == "${_value}" ]]; then
        printf '%s' "${_value}"
    else
        printf '## Error - return_scrubbed_arg detected differences in values\n' >&2
        return 1
    fi
}


argument_parser(){
    local -n _arg_user_ref="${1:?# No reference to an argument list/array provided}"
    local -n _arg_accept_ref="${2:-_DEFAULT_ACCEPTABLE_ARG_LIST}"
    _args_user_list=("${_arg_user_ref[@]}")
    unset _assigned_args
    for _acceptable_args in ${_arg_accept_ref[@]}; do
        ## Take a break when user supplied argument list becomes empty
        [[ "${#_args_user_list[@]}" == '0' ]] && break
        ## First in listed acceptable arg is used as variable name to save value to
        ##  example, '--foo-bar fizz' would transmute into '_foo_bar=fizz'
        _opt_name="${_acceptable_args%%[:|]*}"
        _var_name="${_opt_name#*[-]}"
        _var_name="${_var_name#*[-]}"
        _var_name="_${_var_name//-/_}"
        ## Divine the type of argument allowed for this iteration of acceptable args
        case "${_acceptable_args}" in
            *':'*) _opt_type="${_acceptable_args##*[:]}" ;;
            *)     _opt_type="bool"                      ;;
        esac
        ## Set case expressions to match user arguments against and for non-bool type
        ##  what alternative case expression to match on.
        ##  example '--foo|-f' will also check for '--foo=*|-f=*'
        _arg_opt_list="${_acceptable_args%%:*}"
        _valid_opts_pattern="@(${_arg_opt_list})"
        case "${_arg_opt_list}" in
            *'|'*) _valid_opts_pattern_alt="@(${_arg_opt_list//|/=*|}=*)" ;;
            *)     _valid_opts_pattern_alt="@(${_arg_opt_list}=*)"        ;;
        esac
        ## Attempt to match up user supplied arguments with those that are valid
        for (( i = 0; i < "${#_args_user_list[@]}"; i++ )); do
            _user_opt="${_args_user_list[${i}]}"
            case "${_user_opt}" in
                ${_valid_opts_pattern})     ## Parse for script-name --foo bar or --true
                    if [[ "${_opt_type}" =~ ^'bool'* ]]; then
                        _var_value="$(return_scrubbed_arg "${_user_opt}" "${_opt_type}")"
                        _exit_status="${?}"
                    else
                        i+=1
                        _var_value="$(return_scrubbed_arg "${_args_user_list[${i}]}" "${_opt_type}")"
                        _exit_status="${?}"
                        unset _args_user_list[$(( i - 1 ))]
                    fi
                ;;
                ${_valid_opts_pattern_alt}) ## Parse for script-name --foo=bar
                    _var_value="$(return_scrubbed_arg "${_user_opt#*=}" "${_opt_type}")"
                    _exit_status="${?}"
                ;;
                *)                          ## Parse for script-name direct_value
                    case "${_opt_type}" in
                        *'nil'|*'none')
                            _var_value="$(return_scrubbed_arg "${_user_opt}" "${_opt_type}")"
                            _exit_status="${?}"
                        ;;
                    esac
                ;;
            esac
            if ((_exit_status)); then return ${_exit_status}; fi
            ## Break on matched options after clearing temp variables and re-assigning
            ##  list (array) of user supplied arguments.
            ## Note, re-assigning is to ensure the next looping indexes correctly
            ##  and is designed to require less work on each iteration
            if [ -n "${_var_value}" ]; then
                declare -g "${_var_name}=${_var_value}"
                declare -ag "_assigned_args+=('${_opt_name}=\"${_var_value}\"')"
                unset _user_opt
                unset _var_value
                unset _args_user_list[${i}]
                unset _exit_status
                _args_user_list=("${_args_user_list[@]}")
                break
            fi
        done
        unset _opt_type
        unset _opt_name
        unset _var_name
    done
}
```

> Note, the source code for [`argument-parser.sh`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/argument-parser/blob/master/argument-parser.sh) is a Git Submodule maintained on GitHub at [`bash-utilities/argument-parser`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/argument-parser), and can be cloned individually via...

```
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/bash-utilities
cd ~/git/hub/bash-utilities

git clone git@github.com:bash-utilities/argument-parser.git
```

---

#### [`shared_functions/modules/trap-failure/failure.sh`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure/blob/master/failure.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


# Bash Trap Failure, a submodule for other Bash scripts tracked by Git
# Copyright (C) 2019  S0AndS0
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published
# by the Free Software Foundation; version 3 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


## Outputs Front-Mater formatted failures for functions not returning 0
## Use the following line after sourcing this file to set failure trap
##    trap 'failure "LINENO" "BASH_LINENO" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${?}"' ERR
failure(){
    local -n _lineno="${1:-LINENO}"
    local -n _bash_lineno="${2:-BASH_LINENO}"
    local _last_command="${3:-${BASH_COMMAND}}"
    local _code="${4:-0}"

    ## Workaround for read EOF combo tripping traps
    ((_code)) || {
      return "${_code}"
    }

    local _last_command_height="$(wc -l <<<"${_last_command}")"

    local -a _output_array=()
    _output_array+=(
        '---'
        "lines_history: [${_lineno} ${_bash_lineno[*]}]"
        "function_trace: [${FUNCNAME[*]}]"
        "exit_code: ${_code}"
    )

    [[ "${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}" -gt '1' ]] && {
        _output_array+=('source_trace:')
        for _item in "${BASH_SOURCE[@]}"; do
            _output_array+=("  - ${_item}")
        done
    } || {
        _output_array+=("source_trace: [${BASH_SOURCE[*]}]")
    }

    [[ "${_last_command_height}" -gt '1' ]] && {
        _output_array+=(
            'last_command: ->'
            "${_last_command}"
        )
    } || {
        _output_array+=("last_command: ${_last_command}")
    }

    _output_array+=('---')
    printf '%s\n' "${_output_array[@]}" >&2
    exit ${_code}
}
```

> Note, the source code for [`failure.sh`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure/blob/master/failure.sh) is a Git Submodule maintained on GitHub at [`bash-utilities/trap-failure`](https://github.com/bash-utilities/trap-failure), and can be cloned individually via...

```
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/bash-utilities
cd ~/git/hub/bash-utilities

git clone git@github.com:bash-utilities/trap-failure.git
```